# the search resets valuee of checkboxes in the bulk operation

Tags: search, laravel-backpack, bulk-operations

How to prevent backpackforlaravel from searching reset the bulk operation checkbox?
Method:

1. I mark rows in a table with 10000 rows.
2. I will search for more records and mark them.
3. I delete the string from the search field.
4. I find that only the latest records are marked.
5. The entries for step 1 are unmarked.

How do I ensure that the records from step 1 and step 2 remain marked?